# Is it possible to execute hg clone where the source is a local file location and the destination is a web address (http)?

Tags: http, mercurial, clone

I get the error:

> abort: cannot create new http repository.

Comment: Yes. I am now going to try using ssh to remote-create the clone. I had some problems getting an ssh server. Finally got cygwin downloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct.  You can't create HTTP repositories using clone -- hgweb (the mercurial side of the web repo) doesn't support that functionality.

You can remote-create using 'ssh', or do a 'hg init' on the HTTP server and the push via HTTP, but you cant' use a http clone destination.

Here's a terrible way to make it possible http://ry4an.org/unblog/post/2009-09-17/ but that functionality was omitted for good security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on the webserver and share your local repo via the hg serve command you can clone the local repo to the server.  If you do not have access to the webserver you need to create a new project and put all the files in.

Also, if you dont want to run a local server but do have access to the webserver you can just copy the .hg folder from your repo to the repo group on the server and it will pick it up if your hgweb is configured correctly.